# Bind dns server in Solaris 10 and win xp clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Added this in zone db file, I am running solaris 10

```
_ldap._tcp.mydomain.com. SRV 0 0 389 dc.mydomain.com.
_kerberos._tcp.mydomain.com. SRV 0 0 88 dc.mydomain.com.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.com. SRV 0 0 389 dc.mydomain.com.
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.com. SRV 0 0 88 host.mydomain.com.
```

Now I get this error when I try to join win xp to the domain

The query was for the `SRV` record for `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.com`

The following domain controllers were identified by the query: `host.mydomain.com`

Common causes of this error include:

Host (A) records that map the name of the domain controller to its IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.

Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

What do I need to change in order my win xp join the domain

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `A` records for dc.mydomain.com and host.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for you to do is to allow your Windows Domain Controller to write to the DNS domain used by the Active Directory. At a minimum it should be allowed full access to write to the service domains. Once you adjust the BIND configuration to allow that, then on the Windows Domain Controller run : netdiag /fix.